# Force Eclipse CDT makefile to clean file before compiling

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse + CDT for a project.
I'm using the "generate Makefiles automatically" option from my build settings.
I have in one file the date and some values that must be actualized every time the project is compiled. But since I don't change every time this file the compiler doesn't refresh it.
Is there any option so I can have a Phony target?

if I could just add some lines to the makefile will work
    `rm -f *.o target`
but this will be removed the next time I update my project.

I found that in the settings >> c/c++ build >> behaviour there is an opportunity to write some clean variables. Could this help? I tried to write the file name but this does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give CDT a pre-build command. For me (3.6.2 on Linux):

- `Project` → `Properties`
- `C/C++ Build` category
- `Settings` sub-category
- `Build Steps` tab
- `Pre-build steps` pane
- Enter a command to delete the object file in question (`rm f.o`, or somesuch)

Comment: thank you  a lot. This is exactly what I was searching for. I'm sorry I could not vote you up, but I need 15 points status :)

Comment: @dispatcher: No worries. I hope this goes some small way to re-paying the help I've had from SO.

Comment: @dispatcher: See Eclipse bug 340300 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=340300). Pre-build is broken for parallel builds, though there is an easy work-around.

Comment: I'm using CodeWarrior/Eclipse with CDT 8.1, on Windows. 'touch' seems to work ok here (touch  "${ProjDirPath}/../Sources/version.c"). I guess it supports some linux style commands, not exactly sure how. Unfortunately for me this makes the entire project rebuild each time, and I haven't resolved that yet.

Comment: I finally had success adding this to the post-build step command: ' & touch "${ProjDirPath}/../Sources/version.c"'. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can user **make clean** on Pre-build steps

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the Pre-build steps and it seems to work great:

```
del ${CWD}\addtional_dir\file.o
```