# GNU Make Incremental Build: Force rebuild of specific file

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, incremental-build

I'm using Eclipse (Juno) + CDT on Windows 7 to drive GCC, with automatic makefile generation. Worked great up until I used GCC's `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` preprocessor macros to add a build date/timestamp in my project configuration header file.

On a clean build, these macros work great - but on an incremental build, Make doesn't rebuild the associated object file; it just jumps straight to linking.

I tried doing the Windows equivalent of `touch` as a pre-build step (described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command) but Make still skips the file. Also tried to "touch" a source file that includes the header; still no dice.

How can I tell Make to always rebuild any files that depend on a particular header, even on an incremental build?

Comment: Tried using the `--assume-new` command line option to make, both for the header and an including C file, with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to delete the object file as a pre-build step, as described here:

[Force Eclipse CDT makefile to clean file before compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391590/force-eclipse-cdt-makefile-to-clean-file-before-compiling) (this is possibly a duplicate of that question)

Answer (score 3):

Mark the header as `.PHONY`. That will ensure it is always considered not up to date:

```
.PHONY: particular_header.h
```

Comment: Thanks - Since the Makefile is auto-generated, is there a way to configure this in CDT's C Build Settings?